# System32 is current working directory in Windows?

Tags: windows

I just noticed that under Windows system32 is the current working directory (instead of the directory the executed file is located in). Why is that so? Is it always the case?
And is this intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current directory is set as part of process startup. Once the process starts it is at liberty to change its current directory as it pleases.

The current directory is specified as a parameter to [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx), and indeed any of the other similar API functions that are used to create processes. It is quite common to pass `NULL` for the current directory of the new process. In that case the current directory of the parent process is used.

So, looking at your specific questions:

> Why is that so?

If the current directory for your process is `system32`, that's because whatever started the process chose to make it so, or your process elected to make it so.

> Is it always the case?

No, both the process creator and the process itself are free to set the current directory.

And is this intended?

> I don't know, because I don't know how your process was created.